# Mysql: To retrieve all rows using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, limit

say i have a table with 5 entries

is there a difference if i do `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 18446744073709551615;`

vs `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1000;` ?

as per [MYSQL Limit syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id4651990)

**To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;**

I am trying to achieve a select all with the keyword **LIMIT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are totally different,

In the first query, no rows will be selected if you have only 5 records.
But in the second query you will have all the 5 rows selected.

Inthe first query, record will be selected from the 96th row and the total number of records will be selected is whatever is the number after the comma.

But in the second query, the first 1000 rows will be selected.

For the edited question::

Both the limits are same, and the execution will be of difference till you have maximum 1000 rows in your table.

Actually, The database scans the full table and while the time of returning the records, It will stop as soon as the limit is attained.

Comment: sorry i edited my question, i mean to say a very large value in the Limit vs a small one when both of those are beyond count of elements inside the table; basically just want to compare LIMIT 18446744073709551615 vs LIMIT 1000 when the table has just 5 entries

Answer (score 1):

i think both will return same and there is no difference at all